# parsing xml for clojure

Tags: xml, clojure

I am a beginner for clojure. I am doing "a xml parsing".

Below is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <books>
      <book>
        <title>The joy of clojure</title>
        <author>Michael Fogus / Chris House</author>
      </book>
      <book>
        <title>Programming clojure</title>
        <author>Stuart Halloway</author>
      </book>
      <book>
        <title>Practical clojure</title>
        <author>Luke Van der Hart</author>
      </book>
</books>
```

I want to get each title and author in book.

```
(use '[clojure.xml])

(def rss (parse "test.xml")) 

(defn parsebyname [node tagname]

  (for [node1 (xml-seq node)
                  :when :tagname (:tag node1))]
            (:content node1))
  )

(defn handlebook [book]

(parsebyname book "title")
(parsebyname book "author")
  )


(defn passxml [x]

 (for [node (xml-seq x)
                  :when (= :book (:tag node))]
           (handlebook node))  
 )
```

I want to wirte a common method "parsebyname" to get text by tagname. But it doesn't work.

Any comments is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I have a comment: `clojure` is not spelled as you wrote it

Comment: Is already fixed your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had a few mistakes including parenthesis unclosed and can be refactor also, I am writing a better approach (without redundancy) and I will post it below current fixed solution

```
(def rss (parse "test.xml"))
(defn parsebyname [node tagname]
  (first (flatten (for [node1 (xml-seq node)
                  :when (= tagname (:tag node1))]
              (:content node1)
              )))
  )

(defn handlebook [book]
  [(parsebyname book :title)
   (parsebyname book :author)]
  )


(defn passxml [x]

  (for [node (xml-seq x)
        :when (= :book (:tag node))]
    (handlebook node))
  )

(passxml rss)
=> (["The joy of clojure" "Michael Fogus / Chris House"] ["Programming clojure" "Stuart Halloway"] ["Practical clojure" "Luke Van der Hart"])
```

**UPDATE: Improved version maintaining your logic, removing redundance**

```
(def rss (parse "test.xml"))

(defn parsebyname [node tagname]
   (for [node1 (xml-seq node)
         :when (= tagname (:tag node1))]
     (:content node1)))

(defn handlebook [book]
  (flatten [(parsebyname (first book) :title)
            (parsebyname (second book) :author)]))


(defn passxml [x]
  (let [res (parsebyname x :book)]
    (map handlebook res)))

(passxml rss )

=>(("The joy of clojure" "Michael Fogus / Chris House") ("Programming clojure" "Stuart Halloway") ("Practical clojure" "Luke Van der Hart"))
```

**SECOND UPDATE Version: using destructuring in handlebook function**

```
(def rss (parse "test.xml"))

(defn parsebyname [node tagname]
   (for [node1 (xml-seq node)
         :when (= tagname (:tag node1))]
     (:content node1)))

(defn handlebook [[title author]]
  (concat (:content title) (:content author)) )

(defn passxml [x]
  (map handlebook (parsebyname x :book)))

(passxml rss )
=> (("The joy of clojure" "Michael Fogus / Chris House") ("Programming clojure" "Stuart Halloway") ("Practical clojure" "Luke Van der Hart"))
```

**Third UPDATE: simplified version** Pay attention on the changed order of arguments in parsebyname function to adapt to `->>`

```
(defn parsebyname [tagname node]
   (for [node1 (xml-seq node)
         :when (= tagname (:tag node1))]
     (:content node1)))

(->> (parse "test.xml")
     (parsebyname :book)
     (map (fn [[title author]]
            (concat (:content title) (:content author))))
    )
=> (("The joy of clojure" "Michael Fogus / Chris House") ("Programming clojure" "Stuart Halloway") ("Practical clojure" "Luke Van der Hart"))
```